# Module in subfolder not found although subfolder is added to Search Paths

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio

A python project opened in Visual Studio 2017 has the following file structure:

```
 - Project
   - data
     - sub
       - __init__.py
       - subscript.py
   - start
     - start.py
   ...
   ...
```

running `start.py` throws

```
  File "C:\Users\MZ\Documents\GitHub\Project\start\start.py", line 4, in <module>
    from data.sub import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data.sub'
```

Even if `data\sub` and `sub` are added to the search Paths in the project.

What is the problem?